# Sprok.trap_class_method(Rails::Mongoid, :load_models) alternative for postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rspec, spork

I'm upgrading my project from mongodb to postgresql. While modifing my spec_helper file I encountered this line: `Spork.trap_class_method(Rails::Mongoid, :load_models)`, which is needed to be updated according to it's alternative in postgresql which I'm unable to find.

Comment: I'm not familiar with mongoid... can you tell us what that method does and I might be able to suggest a pg alternative?

Comment: Spork basically forks a copy of the server each time we run our tests.

Comment: Cool, and what purpose is that for (note: totally clueless about how mongoid works). For comparison - I've never heard of doing that in pg... generally Rails uses transactions that clean out the db after each test. I'm not sure if that's for the same purpose or not.

Comment: Spork improves the loading time of our test suite by starting up Rails application once in the background

Comment: Ah neat. Ok, reading this doc: https://github.com/sporkrb/spork/wiki/Spork.trap_method-Jujitsu it looks like the loading-models thing is specific to mongoid... it's possible that this just won't be a problem with postgres? Have you had a go without to see what the performance is like?

Comment: Performance is very bad. It is taking more than 2 min to load even a single test.

Comment: ouch :( yeah that doesn't seem good.